# Round function added onto query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I'm just learning SQL and I'm looking at some data where I want to count the number of occurances of every distinct value. However, there seems to be a bug in the software that ends up generating values that are 1 or two billionth off from the value it should be and also duplicate values. My boss thinks that the duplicates are even smaller deviations that are small enough that the decimals are being dropped so I want to use a round number to eliminate these erroneous values. Here's the query I've written. How would I best round out the distinct values?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (table1.column1 -
  table2.column2) Difference,
  count(*)
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.column3 = table2.column4
GROUP BY table1.column1 -
  table2.column2
ORDER BY (table1.column1 -
  table2.column2)
```

I've taken out real table/column names but hopefully this is still intact. I want to round that table1.column1 - table2.column2

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the ROUND() function?

Comment: If there is, I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(CAST ((table1.column1 -
  table2.column2) AS decimal (6,2)),-3) Difference,
  count(*)
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.column3 = table2.column4
GROUP BY table1.column1 -
  table2.column2
ORDER BY (table1.column1 -
  table2.column2)
```

Comment: You'll probably want to do the same ROUND() on the GROUP BY

Comment: An error occurred reading in the data set. I'm doing the query in the software.

Comment: I got a second after I clicked ok for the first: Query Failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Your query may have attempted to return more than one column with the same name.

Comment: What happens if you highlight the query, and click on Debug -> "Start Debugging" in SSMS?  Do you see any values there that are null?

Comment: The tables I'm working with is isolated from SSMS so i get an error  that the index was outside the bounds of the array. 

When I put the round() on the order by also, I didn't get an error but it didn't return what I was hoping for. It gave me a single row but I should end up with 4 rows. It looks like it only counted the total entries and rounded down to zero.

Comment: How is it isolated from SSMS?  Can you debug your application up to the point that the query would be executed, and then copy the query into SSMS so you can debug it?  Try changing the values in the ROUND so that they are not outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I'm coming from ignorance. I've just started learning how to work with SQL this past week and only worked with SSMS this week as well. All I can tell you (which might not help) is that the data generated from the software isn't accessed by SSMS and I don't know how to access it.

Comment: I fixed it. instead of the suggested query, I used this: Round((table1.column1 -
  table2.table2), 3)